# HTML Autocomplete not working when trying to type href

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm working my way through my Udemy course and as I'm trying to type href in an HTML section it's not giving me the autocomplete dropdown box or if I manually type it, going blue like the various lines above. I've got all the various extensions loaded and have reloaded VSCode a load of times. Nothing is working. Any ideas?
[href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/092zT.jpg)
[href1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waVtf.jpg)

Comment: Href attribute is written like this  ```<a href="somelink">Link</a>```

Comment: Got it. I was typing in between the <a> tags and not <a HERE>. Thanks mate

Comment: Put the `href` attribute in the a tag. Otherwise it will be written out. Please don't do screenshots - just copy&paste the code here. You can format sections of your question as code (take your time to work with the editor).

Comment: You are missing the point, your autocomplete is working for tags, ```href``` is not a tag it is an attribute and it goes inside of a tag such as ```<a>``` or ```<img>``` etc etc.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks for the pointer on screenshots.

Comment: @MrP Yep, I realised. Sorry and thanks for the pointer. Just learning this so apologies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute "href" is mostly used by tags like `<a>` or `<img>`.

You should use something like that:

```
<a href="https://example.com">Example</a>
```

For more help you can visit [W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yup the href need to be typed in before the the first > and not after similar to the img tag

Comment: To improve this answer, try making it more explicit and detailed.